# not getting array length as expected

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#

use 5.010;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my @person = [ "John", "Barnes" ] ;
my @results = [ ['Chemisty', '87'], ['French', '40'], ['Maths', '90'] ] ;
my @record = [ @person, @results ];

my $person_len = scalar @person;
my $results_len = scalar @results;
my $record_len = scalar @record;

print "======= PERSON [$person_len] ===========\n";
print Dumper @person;
print "========= RESULTS [$results_len] ===========\n";
print Dumper @results;
print "============= RECORD [$record_len] =============\n";
print Dumper @record;
print "**=========================**\n";
```

... when you run this I get a length of one for each array - I was expecting lengths of 2, 3 and 3 respectively

What am I doing wrong here? (other stackoverflow Q&A seems to suggest (to me!) that using scalar as per above was the way!

Comment: Tip: Those `scalar` are redundant since the expressions are already being evaluated in scalar context. You should get rid of them.

Comment: Tip: If you want to dump an array, use `Dumper \@a`, not `Dumper @a`. Less confusing, especially in the very situation you find yourself in

Comment: Are persons and results by any chance related? You may be better served by a complex data structure if that is the case.

Comment: @zdim, The code is building the data structure you mention. I think @person is a person record, and @record is an augmented person record. (`my @record = ( @person, \@results );`?)

Comment: @ikegami That makes sense. (I missed that person is first-last name :(.  They may actually want exactly what they have, with hashrefs (except for `\@results` as you say), so that further person+result in the same format can be tacked onto arrays (`@person` etc).

Answer (score 3):

The `[ ]` constructs an *anonymous array* and returns a reference to it -- a scalar.  So you are assigning a scalar to all three arrays, what creates the first and only element in each.

The last one also has `@person` and `@results` flattened into one list, likely not intended.

I am not sure of the intent of your code but here is a guess as to what you may want

```
my @person  = ("John", "Barnes");
my @results = (['Chemisty', '87'], ['French', '40'], ['Maths', '90']);
my @record  = (\@person, \@results);
```

These are now arrays, first with strings and the other two with array references.

Now you can get sizes as you wanted, but lose that `scalar`: when an array is used in a scalar [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) – assigned to a scalar variable for example – the number of elements is returned.

Comment: Or `my $person_len = scalar @$person;` (where `scalar` might be safely dropped, as in any other scalar context).

Comment: @choroba They also assign to array (not `$person`) so it'd be `@{$person[0]}`. But I thought that it was just a mistake in using `[]`

Answer (score 3):

`[ LIST ]` creates an array, assigns `LIST` to it, then returns a reference to that array as if you had done the following:

```
do { my @anon = ( LIST ); \@anon }
```

This reference is the only thing you assign to your array. Fix:

```
my @person = ( "John", "Barnes" );
my @results = ( ['Chemisty', '87'], ['French', '40'], ['Maths', '90'] );
```

It's unclear what you want `@record` to contain. Is it a reference to `@person` and a reference to `@results`? That's just two elements (but you said you expected 3). Fix:

```
my @record = ( \@person, \@results );
```